# "Minimum legal distance" between neighbor's property line and a plant of woody trees

Tags: property, india, indian-constitutional-law, trees

As we know that trees are essential everywhere but they sometimes cause nuisances as well when not properly planted or maintained.

Keeping this in mind, has there been made any **law** that describes the **minimum distance** between the **plant of a woody tree** and **neighbor's property line which is also one of the walls of his/ her building?**

I would like to have the answer in the context of **India.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this will be adressed in the constitution, more in the area's regulations...

Answer (score 3):

Usually this answer would be provided by a local government land use ordinance, and not by the constitution, national law, state law or common law caselaw rules.

It would vary considerably from place to place within India.

You would need to review your local land use ordinances to find the answer.